# What's the difference between Normal and True Normal?

Tags: normals, geometry

In the Cycles node editor, for materials, you can get some information about the object, which the material is being applied to, by using a `Geometry` node.

Among others, you can get the objects *Normal* and... it's ***True** Normal*. This suggests that the first is fake or not as accurate, which makes no sense. This leads me to my question - what is the *technical* difference between an object's *Normal* and it's ***True** Normal*?

Comment: My first thought is that Normal includes any normalmap or bumpmap and True Normal gives you the normal of the actual geometry. I'm guessing here, so I won't give this as an answer.

Comment: @SixthOfFour I looked it up on the Blender Wiki, and it looks like you are correct.

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise I've already read your answer, and upvoted it. ;)

Comment: @someonewithpc Could you please accept the answer? Or does it not answer your question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Blender Wiki states that

> Normal = Shading normal at the surface (includes smooth normals and
>   bump mapping).
>
> True Normal = Geometry or flat normal of the surface.

The normal value takes into account your shading technique, while the true normal uses the actual face direction.

Comment: Is there any other way to influence the normal in blender? I thought it was effectively *normal* = smooth shaded normals (if enabled), and *true normal* = flat shaded normals.

Comment: That is basically it, the normal Normal includes Bump Mapping, however.

Comment: Does this mean, then, that true normal and normal output the same value if the object has flat shading and uses no normal map?

Comment: Because it looks like it's a bit more complicated than that.

Comment: @mqbakamqbaka My understanding is that they will be functionally the same, which lines up with my testing and usage. However they may use different methods to achieve the same/similar result.